# Pandas, integer variable becomes float if contains Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Although there are a lot of discussion in OS that mentions capability of having Nan integer has been added to Pandas from 0.24 onward, but when i read a **csv** file using `read_csv()`  it again detects `integer` value that contains **Nan** as `float`.

Am i doing something wrong or this is normal behavior?
If so, what is would be the fix for this?

all it's important that in my use-case i can detect variable's type properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `astype()` it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"intwithnan":[random.randint(0,100) 
                                 if random.randint(0,3)<2 else np.nan 
                                 for i in range(20)]}).astype({"intwithnan":"Int64"})
df.to_csv("nan.csv", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("nan.csv").astype({"intwithnan":"Int64"})
print(f"{df.dtypes}\n\n{df.to_string(index=False)}")
```

**output**

```
intwithnan    Int64
dtype: object

 intwithnan
         97
         97
         66
         16
       <NA>
       <NA>
       <NA>
         59
         23
       <NA>
       <NA>
         95
         61
       <NA>
         26
         13
       <NA>
         48
         84
         19
```

### supplementary

If you do not know your columns but you want to attempt to convert them to `Int64`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"intwithnan":[random.randint(0,100) 
                                 if random.randint(0,3)<2 else np.nan 
                                 for i in range(20)],
                  "stringcol":["abc" for i in range(20)]}).astype({"intwithnan":"Int64"})
df.to_csv("nan.csv", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("nan.csv")
for c in df.columns:
    try: df = df.astype({c:"Int64"})
    except TypeError: pass
print(f"{df.dtypes}\n\n{df.to_string(index=False)}")
```

Comment: The thing is that user can load different dataset, in which i do not know what columns are actually integer to use `astype()`. during the process of `read_csv()` pandas detect types automatically. is it possible to force it to load integer columns with Nan values as integer and not float

Comment: @MohamadArmoon simple right,  just try each column.  Updated answer with another piece of code

Comment: It sounds reasonable. I thought maybe prevent additional traverse over all dataset. but it seems inevitable

Comment: you could use `df.dtypes.to_dict()` and only attempt to convert float64 columns as a more efficient version